# Apex param not passing the value in Selectlist

Tags: apex, apex-param

The Selectlist is working fine, the value of the the selection pass properly to the controller, but the param value will not pass to the controller.

**PAGE**

```
<apex:page controller="MS4_class" sidebar="false">
    <apex:form >        
        <apex:selectList id="SelectedVW" value="{!SelectedVW}" size="1" multiselect="false" style="width:150px">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!ListOfVW}" />                
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!getMSListPR}">
                <apex:param name="SearchEngine" value="cat" assignTo="{!SearchEngine}" />
            </apex:actionSupport>
        </apex:selectList> 
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: You don't need to write `actionSupport` to pass selected value to controller. Refer this [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectOptions.htm)

Comment: Please share your controller code too.

Comment: @RohitMourya I need both variables in controller, so I though I need the param. Can I pass otherwise two variables to the controller if I select an option?

Comment: If you want values on change of any event then only use `actionsupport` or `actionFunction` otherwise on button click these values will be automatically available in controller since you must have defined them using `{get;set;}`.

Comment: @RohitMourya If you can see, I have an on change event and I use the actionsupport, but I can just pass one value to the controller. Or it is possible to pass more variables with the actionsuppert?

Comment: yes, just add one more `<apex:param>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass param value in controller we must use `rerender` attribute. Use `rerender` attribute with your `apex:actionSupport`. It will solve your issue.

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!getMSListPR}" rerender="none">
      <apex:param name="SearchEngine" value="cat" assignTo="{!SearchEngine}" />
</apex:actionSupport>
```

Comment: Which object is to rerender?

Comment: @peXeq check my update answer. You can rerender complete form or just use none.